# Skip a function if it stalls

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

I wrote a simple module that copies files from a server to specific network folders based on file name. Then, I run multiple instances of the module on different directories, file name keywords, etc. Looks like this:

```
autoCopy(directory1, directory2, keyword1, fileExt)
autoCopy(directory1, directory3, keyword2, fileExt)
autoCopy(directory2, directory3, keyword1, fileExt)
etc...
```

It works fine, except sometimes the connection gets hung up, freezes and eventually kills IDLE - no error message. It's often with the same folder, but varies.

So, I would like to try the function. If it stalls for more than 30 seconds, continue to the next instance. The solutions I've found so far are based on error message, but I want this based on performance.

Comment: create thread for it

Comment: I'm new to Stack. What's the difference between a thread and a question? And, how do I create a thread?

Comment: read https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. This looks promising.